# Do I need SSL for Electronic Signature Form?

Tags: ssl

I'm planning on using an online contract form where customers will agree to certain terms and conditions and sign with an electronic signature (using the mouse to spell their name).  I'm wondering if this type of signature should be encrypted or if this information doesn't really need the extra layer of protection.  Ideally I think having the extra layer of protection would be a good choice, but I'm a little strapped on cash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get certificate for free from [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Its better than nothing.

Comment: Wasn't aware of this option.  Thanks!